# How to create a report of all contact organizations?

Tags: contacts

Creating a report of constituent individuals appears to be easy, but I can't see how to create a report of all organizations.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found learned that contacts can be filtered by contact type, so when I create a report I can use that filter. Duh..

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer as it seems to solve the question